# Plugin options missing in wp-options, how can I fix this?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I installed a plugin in my dev environment and it worked fine, so I tried it on my production site. I found that a submit button was sending me to our 404 page. I then compared the files in ftp to my local environment and found them to be the same. After that it occurred it may be a database issue.

I then compared the tables and found that the dev environment that works has some entries in the wp-options table, that are missing from the production version. I then deactivated and deleted, then reinstalled it hoping it would add the entries. It did not.

I thought that I would try to remove all entries added from the plugin, then deactivate delete and reinstall, still it did not add anything back. Is there something the plugin could be checking to see if it has been installed before, and therefore is failing to create the entries, I only removed the transients in the wp-option table when I tried to clean it up.

I am at a loss as to what to do to ge the plugin working, and I really believe it all comes down tot he database. Anyone have experience in this?

Answer (score 0):

You could export/import your local database to the production site.